# android data fetching is very slow from online web server

Tags: android, json, webserver

i am fetching 104 variables from MySQL through php in android and trying to show in list view but its taking almost 1 - 2 minutes to load values how to speed up the data fetching.

i am using json for fetching data, any other library's for fast fetching.

please explain with complete example.

Comment: you will get lot of down votes for these kinda questions. what checks have you done? have you tried to see this JSON loading in a browser? whats the time taken? have u used jmeter to see whats the response time?

Comment: i dont know regarding jmeter, json loading time i am a complete beginner and asking my doubt should not down vote me

Comment: thanks for jmeter it takes 125ms total 204 variables i am fetching

Comment: so the issue is not at your server. its at the client... what do you use at your client end? is it just http req/resp or u use square's retrofit?

Comment: i have used volley library to fetch data and its very fast in fetching data within 4 - 5 seconds 204 variables are fetched.Thanks for help @  rakesh kashyap

Answer (score 1):

Try the Android Asynchronous Http Client library

Features

- Using upstream HttpClient of version 4.3.6 instead of Android provided DefaultHttpClient
- Compatible with Android API 23 and higher
- Make asynchronous HTTP requests, handle responses in anonymous callbacks
  HTTP requests happen outside the UI thread
- Requests use a threadpool to cap concurrent resource usage
  GET/POST params builder (RequestParams)
- Multipart file uploads with no additional third party libraries
- Streamed JSON uploads with no additional libraries
- Handling circular and relative redirects
- Tiny size overhead to your application, only 90kb for everything
- Automatic smart request retries optimized for spotty mobile connections
- Automatic gzip response decoding support for super-fast requests
- Binary protocol communication with BinaryHttpResponseHandler
- Built-in response parsing into JSON with JsonHttpResponseHandler
- Saving response directly into file with FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler
- Persistent cookie store, saves cookies into your app’s SharedPreferences
- Integration with Jackson JSON, Gson or other JSON (de)serializing libraries with BaseJsonHttpResponseHandler
- Support for SAX parser with SaxAsyncHttpResponseHandler
- Support for languages and content encodings, not just UTF-8

For more details please visit these link :

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Here's an example of using it :

```
pdialog.setMessage("Veuillez patienter!");
                pdialog.show();
                RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

                params.put("user_login", username);



                AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                client.post("http://yourUrl.com", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                        loading = true;

                        AdapterPrincipal adapterPrincipal;
                        String s = "";
                        try {

                            s = new String(responseBody, "UTF-8");
                            Log.d("Error", s.toString());
                            JSONObject arrg = new JSONObject(s);
                            JSONArray query = arrg.getJSONArray("query");
                            Log.i("result from query ", "" + query);
                            for (int i = 0; i < query.length(); i++) {
                                try {

                                    pdialog.dismiss();
                                    JSONObject object = query.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String dateinsertannonce = object.getString("date_insert_annonce");
                                    Log.i("date", dateinsertannonce);
                                    String datevente = object.getString("vendu");
                                    String marque = object.getString("marque");
                                    String Clomn_Model = object.getString("model");
                                    String Clomn_Prix = object.getString("prix");
                                    String Clomn_Kilometrage = object.getString("kilometrage");
                                    String Clomn_BoiteVitesse = object.getString("boite_vitesse");
                                    String Clomn_Energie = object.getString("energie");
                                    String Clomn_Source = object.getString("source");
                                    String Clomn_Url = object.getString("url");
                                    String Clomn_PHOTO = object.getString("images_noms");
                                    String Maj = object.getString("derniere_maj");
                                    int id = object.getInt("id");



                                   voitureList = databaseHelper.getAllVoiture(username, currentLength);


                                    listView.setAdapter(new AdapterLogin(getActivity(), voitureList, username, currentLength));


                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }
```